# Incorrect frame of UIScrollview in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using Xcode7.3.1.My ViewController contains structure like
`UIScrollview`->`UIView`->`UIScrollview`. I am using auto layout for these view.I tried to print my inner scrollview frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but i am not getting exact frame.In xib part of viewController does not shows any errors for autoLayout.
Please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Actually `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` called more than one time... so you might have checked the frame when first time it get called.. it is better that if you shift your code from there to `viewDidAppear`, here it will get called single time and the frame will be same as you expected

Comment: its not working

Comment: Then it must be problem with your autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a fairly old question but I just ran into this issue and found a (hacky) solution. It seems like this is a bug in the SDK. What happens is that the content of the scroll view doesn't get laid out before `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like you would expect. So my solution is to force it.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    // now scroll view content should laid out as expected
}
```